# /usr/bin/java: is a directory

Tags: java, linux

I downloaded the jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz file from the Oracle website, unzipped it and also created a symbolic link just like one of the tutorial said. (I'm very new to these things, so I have no idea what a symbolic link means so please explain it.) Right now, whenever I type Java, it says /usr/bin/java is a directory. I can't find any answer to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No need to do all that. Simply add path to your `jdk/bin` to your PATH and export it.

Comment: Have you tried running a search like "what is a symbolic link" in Google?

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using? In many cases the `*.tar.gz` packages are not the best way to install Java...

Comment: A [symbolic-link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (or soft-link) is like a sign that points to the real file that the OS will follow on the user's behalf. You should have linked the java in the bin folder, generally you might extract that `tar.gz` file into `/opt/` or use a distribution specific installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably created a symbolic link to the directory instead of to the actual `java` binary.  You need to give `ln -sh $extracted_path/bin/java` where $extracted_path needs to be replaced with the real base direcory where you extracted the package.